# In Star Trek do the names of species and their ability to interbreed point to a founder species?

Tags: star-trek

Sorry if this has been asked, i searched but found nothing.  We can take these as facts,  that humans/roumlans/vulans/klingons/betazoids/etc can interbreed and have non-sterile children.  We also know that some species like Vulans, Romulans, exist and that in earth mythology those same names occur as names of gods.

It seems to me that this all seems to point to the fact that there was some founding species ages ago who spread their seed and culture through out the galaxy.  From a genetic point of view, the fact that all these species can interbreed should show they diverged from the same genome at some period in the past,  otherwise it is unprecedented to common medical knowledge.

Also imagine that these same founder gods left their culture, their myths, their stories, etc, with their offspring they left on the planet.  Our myths of the gods Vulcan and Romulus/Remus are really just imprints left from the original founders and interpreted/mis-interpreted by us.

Anyway I am just wondering if someone has ever addressed this.  Seems kinda interesting to me.

Comment: Related: [Is there an in-universe explanation for the Roman Empire terminology used for the Romulans?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/70667/2242), [Why aren't more species' planets named differently from their species name?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/6668/2242), [Is the humanoid appearance of most alien species in the Star Trek universe ever canonically addressed?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/6676/2242), [Can you do *that* with just any ole alien?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/109594/2242)...

Comment: More: [How many alien species are compatible with humans?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/125771/2242), [How does cross-species (Klingon/Human, Vulcan/Human) breeding work genetically in Star Trek?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/18622/2242), [Star Trek - What is the relationship between the 'Bread and Circuses' Roman planet and the Romulans?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/45815/2242), [Is the term “Borg” an acronym for something, or is it just an abbreviation of “Cyborg”?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/22718/2242)

Comment: Almost certainly more I missed, and several I intentionally skipped because they were closed as duplicates of these.  Most were found through the "Related" sidebars.

Answer (score 4):

> Yes, there is [a progenitor race](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Ancient_humanoid).

In *Star Trek: The Next Generation* season 6 episode 20 [*The Chase*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Chase_(episode)), the Enterprise-D go on a trip finding various DNA patterns and eventually

> find the progenitor race who left a message hidden inside everyone's DNA, which included the Vulcans, Romulans, Klingons, Humans and Cardassians

Comment: However they didn't influence those successor cultures, and the names we assign to their planets aren't going to be the same names they use for themselves.