# Could Spock mind meld with an animal or dumb humanoid?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, spock

An intelligent animal, say, a dog, chimp, or dolphin. Could Spock meld with such creatures? What about tribbles? Humanoid beings with seemingly small amounts of intelligence, such as the Taurean creatures ("Galileo Seven"), or the Mugato?

Comment: Spock mind-melded with [whales](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Voyage_Home#Filming), but in the Star Trek world [they're sentient](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4670/why-do-other-races-refer-to-us-as-humans/4671#4671).

Comment: He melded with Shatner, so yes.

Comment: @JamesSheridan - Wait... does Shatner exist in Star Trek universe? (Shatner, not Kirk)

Answer (score 2):

There are definitely some examples where he mind melds with non-humanoid aliens or other beings.

One example I immediately remembered from *TOS* would be the episode *The Changeling*, where he's trying to mind-meld with the rogue probe *Nomad*. It obviously works.

I think there are also a few examples during *Voyager*, where *Tuvok* mind melds with sentient but non-humanoid creates in a few cases, but I can't pin any example down right now.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPztpGBrfD8

Comment: @Richard Ah, right, how could I forget that one. :)

Comment: Nomad is clearly an intelligent being. The question asks if Spock can meld with an animal or dumb humanoid, neither of which Nomad is. Also, I don't see the reason why this question is considered "too broad." I thought I explained it pretty well.

Comment: Another one http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Devil_in_the_Dark

Comment: Why do you consider all animals as "dumb"? You haven't seen our dog. ;)

Comment: Well the Horta is considered intelligent having worked out the importance of the circulation pump it stole and acquiring basic writing from a brief contact with Spock