# Why do Starfleet ships employ cetaceans?

Tags: star-trek, spaceship

On certain Starfleet ships (at least the Enterprise-D and the Cerritos), there is an area (essentially a large pool) where sentient dolphins give aid in navigation. This area is called ["cetacean ops"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Cetacean_Ops). Cetacean ops and the employment of sentient dolphins is mentioned in [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/167109/are-there-any-other-sentient-species-on-earth-in-the-star-trek-universe/167110#167110).

Is there some kind of benefit to using cetaceans (dolphins in this case) for aiding in navigation? Aren't humans more than capable of doing the job? Is there some reason that dolphins are better-suited for this job? Dolphins don't have hands, which could potentially complicate things.

Comment: But they think in 3D unlike many humans (like Khan).

Comment: It's a nod to them being human level smart in real life and how advanced TNG was supposedto be over TOS. In-universe the universal translators can handle just about any intelligent space cloud - a dolphin should be trivial.  Yes it is obviously impractical and unnecessary when holograms are more intelligent than people - even people are obsolete.  Star Trek broke its own universe.

Comment: "*According to the Star Trek: The Next Generation Technical Manual, the ship's dolphins work in navigation and are overseen by two whales of species Orcinus orca takayai, or Takaya's Whales. This references the 1988 anime OVA Gunbuster, where the starship Exelion uses dolphins for navigation due to their natural familiarity with moving in three dimensions; as well as the name of that series' protagonist, Noriko Takaya.*"

Comment: @lucasbachmann - I find it amusing that the line that started this all was actually "report to **Station** Ops", but the voice actor misspoke, the editor didn't have time to fix it and thought nobody would notice, and thus a legend was born.

Comment: Also suggested viewing: Rick Sternbach dolphin art.  He was an artist on TNG at the earliest stages and is fond of painting dolphins wearing spacesuits

Comment: Can we have some sources or context here? Where does it say they use dolphins for navigation?

Comment: @Darren see Valorum's comment above. They have always been referred to as dolphins and are clearly depicted as being dolphins in *Lower Decks.* Whales don't squeak. As to context, I was referring to the "cetacean ops" that apparently exist on multiple Starfleet ships.

Comment: @SovereignInquiry You misunderstood my question. I’m not querying if mentioned cetaceans are actually dolphins or not, I’m querying where there is *any* mention of cetaceans being used to navigate. If this is a reference to Lower Decks (which I haven’t seen) can you add it as a tag and reference an appropriate scene or episode in the question?

Comment: @Darren Sorry for my misunderstanding, but Valorum's quote is still relevant.

Comment: @SovereignInquiry but it’s a comment, which is not permanent. And that’s a quote from the TNG technical manual (is that even canon?) which is a niche source at best and somewhere else Lower Decks was mentioned. Even someone who’s seen every episode of TNG will be looking at this question scratching their head asking themselves “what the hell is he on about?”, just as I did, and I own a copy of the technical manual. So all I’m asking for is some reference in the question as to where this idea came from.

Comment: And it’s lot like you’re asking about the use of stars to navigate, which anyone, even having never seen Trek, would understand as something people are likely to do. Ask yourself this; if I posted a question with no other context that said “In Star Wars, why do they consider flinging rocks at each other during space combat to be an effective weapon?” Would you not ask me where I got this idea from and expect me to quote the source?

Comment: The TNG Technical Manual is a very widely-trusted and widely-cited source. Cetacean ops are also included in Rick Sternbach's E-D blueprints. And now that it was [shown in Lower Decks](https://screenrant.com/star-trek-dolphins-lower-decks-tng-cetacean-ops/#:~:text=On%20Star%20Trek%3A%20Lower%20Decks,Starfleet%20uniforms%20and%20comm%20badges.) (which I highly recommend), it is officially canon. I had mistakenly assumed that cetaceans ops was common knowledge. I will provide the Memory Alpha link in the question and a link to another question which includes information about cetacean ops.

Comment: Because if they employed giraffes they'd need taller ceilings.

Comment: @Valorum Interestingly, while OVA Gunbuster was a 1988 release, David Brinn's *Startide Rising* (with the Streaker being mostly dolphin crewed) was published in 1983

Comment: @Darren I guess you could say [cetacean needed] ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple, necessarily out-of-universe answer is: Starfleet probably doesn't employ cetaceans. The "Cetacean Ops" bit in the TNG Technical Manual is a joke, part obvious nod to *Star Trek IV: The Voyage Home*, and part something humorous put there for the kinds of people who enjoy reading *incredibly dense* fictional technical manuals for fun. Cetacean Ops was never directly seen or referenced on screen during TNG's run or during the four movies. (See note below.) *Lower Decks*, ostensibly a comedy series, is just using some "deep cut" background material to make an in-joke to that part of the audience.

Episode writers diverged from the TNG Technical Manual plenty of times on-screen. For just one off-the-cuff example: according to the TNG Technical Manual, a Type-II phaser set to maximum is supposed to release enough energy to vaporize *several thousand cubic meters of rock*. (Apologies for the lack of citations and exact values. My Tech Manual is in a box and unavailable at the time of writing.) And yet, the on-screen usages of the Type-II at maximum -- complete with the FX shot showing all the bars fully lit, so there was no possible alternate interpretation -- did nothing more than vaporize a person. It certainly didn't vaporize the target, everyone else in the room, the room, the phaser itself... :)

If you accept that the TNG Technical Manual is canon, then you might as well start asking about the Enterprise-D's Porsche, the giant rubber duck, the second warp core, and why Starfleet decided it was important to write portions of the *Gilligan's Island* theme song in illegibly small letters on various bulkhead iconography. :)

*(edited to add, because I suspect this will get asked)*

Note re: Geordie's "have you seen the dolphins?" line in *The Perfect Mate*

While I hate to question the correctness of an answer to another question, the source linked in the answer to "Are there any other sentient species on Earth in the Star Trek universe?" for Cetacean Ops does not itself cite any sources. It includes a supposed Rick Sternbach quote without context, and that is all.

Geordie's line was not "Have you seen Cetacean Ops and the dolphins who pilot our ship?", it was "Have you seen the dolphins yet?" The existence of dolphins can be explained away by any number of necessarily hypothetical answers, because that is literally the only on-screen line about that in the episode dialogue.

Comment: Per my comment above, the origin of "cetacean ops" was the mispronunciation of "station ops", and not a reference to ST:IV, although the presence of whales in the film canon probably led to people's misapprehension about what they just heard

Comment: You don't consider Lower Decks to be canon then? Yes, it is more comedic that the other shows, but everything appears to be in-line with post-DS9 canon.

Comment: _Lower Decks_ is garbage.

Answer (score -1):

That comes down to "The Voyage Home" and their Trek-Lore connection to Aliens. I.E. They have an un-replicatable instinct that allows them to know where they are as no computer or human can. Their job is probably a combination of correction when the computer get's confused, and figuring out where a starship is when they're REALLY far out. That's why a federation ship is virtually never "lost" so to speak. It was probably cetaceans who figured out where Enterprise was during the first encounter with the Borg, and allowed Voyager to know they where "THAT" far away from home, along with which direction to go.

P.S. In both instances, I suspect the Dolphins/Whales where all singing, "What the hell just happened out there!?" One sec they're in familiar space, the next they warp a distance that shouldn't be logically possible, even by their standards!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you have any references to support this?

Comment: Yes, this all seems quite reasonable, but you've not offered a lick of evidence to back it up